# how to publish a ganache client in Ubuntu 22.04 to local network

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, home-networking, ufw

I have ganache client installed on my Ubuntu 2204. I want to publish the client for other local computers via port 8545. I run the ganache client via the command:

```
$ ganache-cli --secure -a 10 -e 1000 -u 0 -u 1 -u 2 -l 0x851637 --networkId 100 -h localhost
```

It works just fine in the pc where is deployed. however, I want a third pc to connect it via the local IP. I enable the firewall and add port 8545 via:

```
$ sudo ufw allow from 192.168.3.0/24 to any port 8545
```

It didn't work.
I did the same on port 8000 and deploy a "hello world" node server just for testing the firewall and it work.
I also did something similar and publish a deployed ganache-client on macOS and I was able to connect from the third computer. Of course, macOS has a different firewall structure.
It seems to be the ubuntu firewall.
Anyway, I am out of ideas on how to publish a ganache client on Ubuntu to the local network.. any help?

Thanks in advance.